# Why is CSS part commented in some html pages?

Tags: html, css

I just read this code , and I'm not sure what's the point of doing this.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
h{
    color : blue;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
```

What is the comment symbol `<!-- -->` trying to do here since the CSS does take effect anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To stop very old browsers (such as Netscape 1) that do not recognise the `<style>` tag from rendering the text inside the element.

The technique became pointless when the marketshare of those browsers dropped to "as close to zero as makes no difference" sometime in the 1990s.

Comment: @JrChen — not necessarily, these things become [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) techniques. It probably isn't a very good textbook though.

Comment: @JrChen go ahead to the most modern browsers today, you will learn the web stuff better than having to learn many ways of hacking just for a cross-browser solution. (I hate the day of web programming with just Internet Explorer and Netscape Navigator).